# select node-ancestors recursively

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

Suppose I have the following tree:

[image: tree-visual]

The table that stores the data is presented below accordingly:

| node_id | parent_id |
| --- | --- |
| A | null |
| B | A |
| C | A |
| D | B |

I want to select all node ancestors for every node in the tree.

the root node has no ancestors so it'll not show up.

Example of what I want -

| node_id | ancestor_id |
| --- | --- |
| B | A |
| C | A |
| D | B |
| D | A |

Glad for any help :)

I am working with pgsql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a recursive query :

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
SELECT node_id, parent_id AS ancestor_id
  FROM your_table
 WHERE parent_id is not null
UNION ALL
SELECT children.node_id, parent.parent_id
  FROM cte AS chidren
 INNER JOIN your_table AS parent
    ON parent.node_id = children.parent_id
)
SELECT *
  FROM cte ;
```

This query may not stop if you have a loop in the node_id => paren_id tree. In order to avoid infinite loops in the recursive query, you have to add a test :

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
SELECT node_id, parent_id AS ancestor_id, array[node_id, parent_id] AS check
  FROM your_table
 WHERE parent_id is not null
UNION ALL
SELECT children.node_id, parent.parent_id, children.check || parent.parent_id
  FROM cte AS chidren
 INNER JOIN your_table AS parent
    ON parent.node_id = children.parent_id
 WHERE NOT children.check @> array[parent.parent_id]  -- this condition will avoid infinite loops
)
SELECT node_id, ancestor_id
  FROM cte ;
```

Comment: If you want to filter out the root as requested in the question, you need `where parent_id is not null` in the anchor of the recursive query.

Comment: @GMB : you are right, answer updated